# Is this linear transformation diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

$T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation such that $T^3 = T^2$, $T^2 \ne T$ and $T$ is not nilpotent. Is $T$ diagonalizable?

I haven't tried much since I don't really know where to start.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: @GitGud No, I don't.

Comment: What about Cayley–Hamilton Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know that theorem.

Comment: How about $\large \left\{0, 1\right\}$ eigenvalues ?

Comment: @Nikki Use theo theorem in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48131).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T^3 = T^2$, all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $T$ must satisfy $\lambda^3 = \lambda^2$, so all eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$. Suppose $T$ is diagonalizable. Then $T^2$ and $T^3$ are diagonalizable with the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and you have for any vector $x$ that $x = \sum_i a_i v_i$ where $v_i$ are the eigenvectors of $T$, and then because $T^3 = T^2$ you have $T^3(x) = \sum_i a_i \lambda_i^3 v_i = T^2(x) = \sum_i a_i \lambda_i^2 v_i$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $T$. But this also equals $\sum_i a_i \lambda_i v_i = T(x)$, so $T = T^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has single roots. Now, translate each of the three pieces of information you have received into a statement about the minimal polynomial of $T$.